# How to sequentially execute http get in node

Tags: node.js, rest, http

```
function getStuff(serial){
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
      request("url using serial", function (error, response, body){
        try {
          fulfill(body);
        } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
      }, reject);
    });
}

while(FLAG) {
  var p = getStuff(x);
  p.then(function(obj){
    console.log(obj)
    if(some condition on obj) FLAG = false
  })
  //WAIT HERE TILL ITS DONE!!!!
}
```

How do I use this promise to sequentially execute a series of calls with different serial using a loop?

Comment: Take a look at Promises: https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises alternatively you could use the `async` library: http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Can you show an example using promises? I'll update my code to the work that I have done.

Comment: updated the code. please tell me how to use this promise

Comment: Judging from the comment in the code to wait until all promises have finished, you might be looking for something like this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

You don't have to use bluebird but the .all implementation should be in many promise libs

Answer (score 1):

With node you need to structure your code for asynchronous calls.

kkreft's comment describes some tools you can use to help with this.

An implementation of your code that could work would be:

```
var x = 1
var list = []
function trial(callback) {

  http.get("endpoint url", function (err, response) {
        x++;
        list.append(response.data);

        if (err) 
           callback(err);
        else
           callback(null, x);
    });
}

trial(function(err, r) {
     console.log(r);
     console.log(list);
});
```

Comment: Please check my updated code. I am having trouble managing promises.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't. Anything you want to do with the data coming back from a call like that has to be in the callback. So:

```
var x = 1
function trial() {
  http.get("endpoint url", function (response) {
    x++;
    list.push(response.data);
    console.log(x) // 2
  });

  return x;
}
console.log(trial())// 1
```

The call you're dispatching is asynchronous. At the moment there isn't anything in the spec that lets us wait for the results of a call. All synchronous code (everything you have outside the function) will execute before the results of the call comes back no matter how long it takes. So you have to handle the data inside the callback or something else that manages async like promises.

Comment: Please check my updated code. I am having trouble managing promises. I understand the concepts but I am having converting it into code.